# "which of you are'' or ''which of you is''?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

> *So, you're a bunch of psychics?*
>
> *Which of you **is** professor X and which of you **is** Jean Grey then?*

or should it be

> *Which of you **are** professor X and which of you **are** Jean Grey then?*

Here I'm talking to a particular group of folks that is in front of me and so they are in second person. So it could be **are**, but then **is** sounds better.

Which is correct then?

Comment: It depends how many there are of each.

Comment: No. There are not multiple Professors X, in spite of @tchrist's  playing at silly buggers. It couldn't be "are" in English. **Is** "sounds better" because **are** is wrong. A singular complement (Professor X) calls for a singular verb.

Comment: "Which of you" is understood as "which one of you"?, so singular agreement is required, but cf. "Which (ones of) you are professors"?

Comment: Notice how one says "which of us is" not "which of us am". That shows that the "of you" part is not what governs the verb.

Answer (score 2):

*Which* can be either singular or plural, but it always takes a third-person verb; so in your example we say *is* (third-person singular).

Interestingly, however, we can say things like:

> Which of you forgot your coat?

where the second-person possessive pronoun *your* seems to have "which of you" as its antecedent. (But a third-person pronoun, such as *his* if all possibilities are male, would also work here, and is probably better in formal contexts.)

Comment: What grammatical persons can **your** be in this example?

Comment: @GJC: *Your* is inherently second-person, but since nothing ever needs to agree with a possessive pronoun, there's no specific evidence of that. If you want to examine that question, a better example is something like "One of you needs to write a paragraph about something you're proud of", where
 *one of you* is third-person (*needs*) and *you* is second-person (*'re*), even though the former seems to be the latter's antecedent.

Comment: _Use a singular verb after which if only one person or thing is meant; use a plural verb if it is more than one: Which of the applicants has got the job? (= Although there was more than one applicant, I know that only one has got the job.) • Which of the patients have recovered? (= It is possible that more than one patient has recovered.)_  https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/which_1

Comment: @GJC: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

When you ask *which of you [is/are]...*, what you're really asking is *which **one** (of you) [is/are]...* The *of you* part just defines the group from which the answer is selected.  It's not *which Beatle* or *which prime minister*, it's *which of you*.  Okay, but for the purposes of grammar, that's not really necessary.

So let's take that out and see what we have:

> Which is professor X and which is Jean Grey then?

Since we're looking for only one person to play each part, the real question is:

> Which **one** is professor X and which **one** is Jean Grey then?

And, since *one* is singular, it needs the singular form of the verb, *is*.